# Java: How to load Class stored as byte[] into the JVM?

Tags: java, classloader

If one has serialized the entire .class file into byte[], and assuming the name of the class is known (passed along with the byte[]), how do you convert byte[] -> Class -> then load it to the JVM so that I could later use it by calling the Class.forName()?

**NOTE:**
I'm doing this because I sent the .class over to another host, and the host's JVM doesn't know about this .class.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'm actually using something like this right now in a test to give a set of Class definitions as byte[] to a ClassLoader:

```
  public static class ByteClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {
    private final Map<String, byte[]> extraClassDefs;

    public ByteClassLoader(URL[] urls, ClassLoader parent, Map<String, byte[]> extraClassDefs) {
      super(urls, parent);
      this.extraClassDefs = new HashMap<String, byte[]>(extraClassDefs);
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> findClass(final String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
      byte[] classBytes = this.extraClassDefs.remove(name);
      if (classBytes != null) {
        return defineClass(name, classBytes, 0, classBytes.length); 
      }
      return super.findClass(name);
    }

  }
```

Comment: Alex, but what if 2 .class are dependent on one another? would it still work?

Comment: Probably not.  You should probably be sending (for example) a JAR file not a sequence of separate .class files.

Comment: @ShaChris23 - sure, why wouldn't it?  

@Stephen C - that seems like a limited view of what Java classloaders can do.  Why do you say probably not?

Answer (score 9):

Use the defineClass(String, byte[], int, int) method from [ClassLoader](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html)

Answer (score 7):

Extend `ClassLoader` and then implement the necessary call to obtain your `byte[]` inside the method `defineClass()`.  Conversely you can do this in `findClass()`.  You'll thus load this ClassLoader at the beginning or employ it when you need class definitions via your array.

```
public class ByteArrayClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

    public Class findClass(String name) {
        byte[] ba = /* go obtain your byte array by the name */;

        return defineClass(name,ba,0,ba.length);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so here's what I did:

```
public class AgentClassLoader extends ClassLoader
{
  public void loadThisClass(ClassByte classByte_)
  {
    resolveClass(defineClass(classByte_.getName(),
                             classByte_.getBytes(),
                             0,
                             classByte_.getBytes().length));
  }
}
```

I hope that loads the class into JVM? If this really works, why didn't Java implementator make both defineClass and resolveClass public methods? I really wonder what they were thinking. Anyone can enlighten me?

Just for completeness,  here's ClassByte

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class ClassByte implements Serializable
{
  private String name;
  private byte[] bytes;

  ClassByte(String name_, byte[] bytes_)
  {
    name  = name_;
    bytes = bytes_;
  }

  public String getName()
  {
    return name;
  }

  public byte[] getBytes()
  {
    return bytes;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that the idea is to discourage random code from calling `defineClass` on the system/default class loaders.  This has the potential to compromise security and generally make **really strange** things happen.  It is better to only allow this on custom classloaders.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Alex is correct but if you have inheritance relationship between classes you need to make sure you load the parent class first. Otherwise the class loader won't be able to define it.

Comment: Really? I think that is a linkage problem rather than a class definition problem. Classes don't need to be defined in the right order, otherwise we couldn't have circular dependencies in classes. For example, Class.getName() returns a String but String.getClass() returns a Class. Furthermore, both classes have a parent of Object but Object.toString() and Object.getClass() return String and Class respectively. If what you were saying were true there would be no order correct to load these classes.

Comment: @Kidburla that's because the JVM does loading for classes when they are needed, so you can load Class without needing String loaded, and String will be loaded when you call `getName`. However, super-class/interfaces need to be loaded with or before the class being loaded, otherwise the class is incomplete. That's why we can't have circular inheritance, because the class loaders don't know how to deal with that.

Comment: True. Sorry, I misread "inheritance" as "dependent" because of comments on the accepted answer.

Comment: @ıɯɐƃoʇǝızuǝʞ The reason why you can't have circular inheritance is because it is a logical impossibility, not because there would be difficulties loading it.  And super-class/interfaces do not need to be loaded before the class being loaded, because this would also lead to a logical impossibility: you don't know what the super is unless you have loaded the class first, so you cannot load the super before the class.