# Java: new instance from bytecode

Tags: java, reflection, assembly, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

```
ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(...);
byte[] bytes = cw.toByteArray();
```

I would like to create new class instance from `bytes` array. How do I do this? Is it possible at all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: How to load Class stored as byte\[\] into the JVM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781091/java-how-to-load-class-stored-as-byte-into-the-jvm)

Comment: @bruno conde: It looks like. We just express things in a more concise way here

Comment: You can use defineClass, however unless you use a custom class loader you may need to use reflections to call it as its not a public method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ClassLoader.defineClass()
```

Reference:

- [ClassLoader.defineClass(String name, byte[] b, int off, int len)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass%28java.lang.String%2C%20byte%5B%5D%2C%20int%2C%20int%29)

Comment: Nice answer but awful formatting and a java 1.4 link. Changed both.

Comment: thanks for editing, was struggling with that, but parser didn't want to show the link properly.

Comment: +1. Anyway, the method is protected, so you'll need a way to access it. Extending the ClassLoader and providing a public method could be a solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible, and you need to use Reflection in order to achieve this.  The psuedo code is:

```
final Class clazz = loadIntoCurrentClassLoader(bytes); //I'm assuming you wrote this already using defineClass

final YourClass foo ;
try {
    foo = (YourClass) clazz.newInstance();
}
catch (final Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `loadIntoCurrentClassLoader(bytes)` part is what the question is about :-)

Comment: Ok so I went a little overboard ;)

Comment: It's ambiguous from the way the question is phrased.

Comment: The point is not clazz.newInstance(). The point here was how to get clazz. Reflection does not help here, you should use classLoader.defineClass()

Answer (score 0):

I can create the class by extending ClassLoader and using defineClass. But then the created class has my extended ClassLoader as its ClassLoader, which causes failures when the code of my class loads other classes. Presumably I can get around this by creating my ClassLoader to delegate everything in the right way, but it's not obvious how to get this right.