# How to loop through classes in a folder and from each class use a method?(No clue where to start)

Tags: java, loops

What I'm trying to do is have a folder with classes in it. Then be able to loop through those classes, and trigger a method named "String getVariables(Object player, String line)".

But I have no clue where to start...

Comment: Are you expecting many of the classes in that folder to have versions of that method?  If so, do they share a common interface or abstract superclass where that method is declared?

Comment: Why is it "getVariables" when it returns a String? Why does every class have a getVariables that takes an "Object" player and a "String" line (is there a relationship there)? Do you have instances of these classes? If not, do they have default constructors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will not provide you with code but i will send you in a direction which will resolve your issue.

1: Locate the files(Which are Classes), store them in an array if you want.

2: Create a ClassLoader/URLClassLoader and set the url to the path of the file{http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html}

3: Depending on what the access of the method is(Static/Instance) you will either need to create an instance of that class or just invoke the static method, this can be acomplished with reflection{http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/}

This question has been asked a few times or questions similar to yours.

[Method to dynamically load java class files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219829/method-to-dynamically-load-java-class-files)

[Java: How to load Class stored as byte[] into the JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781091/java-how-to-load-class-stored-as-byte-into-the-jvm)

[How do I invoke a Java method when given the method name as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string)

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't looking for the code, just a kick in the right direction.