# How can Java deserialize Class objects while preserving their identity to currently loaded Class objects?

Tags: java, serialization, classloader

If I serialize a `Class` object (for example, `HashMap.class`), and then deserialize it in another instance of JVM, it turns out that the deserialized class is identical to the one currently loaded:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;

final class DeserializationTest {

    static String path = "/home/suseika/test.ser";
    static Class<HashMap> cls = HashMap.class;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args[0].equals("serialize")) {
            serialize();
        } else if (args[0].equals("deserialize")) {
            final Object deserialized = deserialize();

            // The important line, prints "true"
            System.out.println(deserialized == cls); 
        }
    }

    static Object deserialize() throws Exception {
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(path));
        return in.readObject();
    }

    static void serialize() throws Exception {
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
        out.writeObject(cls);
        out.close();
        fileOut.close();
    }
}
```

How is Java able to deserialize objects in this case so that identity is preserved? `Class` doesn't seem to implement `writeObject()`/`readObject()`/`readResolve()`.

Can this behavior be broken with loading a particular class/using a particular classloader/using a particular JVM setup/doing something during serialization? Are there instances where the loaded `Class` would not be the same as the deserialized one? In other words, can I rely on this behavior in my application to serialize and deserialize `Class` objects?

Comment: IMHO: a deserialized class object should be indistinguishable of a "standard" class object of the same type. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/serialized-form.html#java.lang.Class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is Java able to deserialize objects in this case so that identity is preserved?

This is because class instances are cached by the classloader.

[Does Java guarantee that Object.getClass() == Object.getClass()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738919/does-java-guarantee-that-object-getclass-object-getclass)

> Can this behavior be broken with loading a particular class/using a particular classloader/using a particular JVM setup/doing something during serialization?

For serialized instances of classes from packages not starting with `java.*` this can be broken using different classloaders in `ObjectInputStream` (an example  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35750294/4483113)).

For classes in `java.*` like your case (`java.lang.Class`), only the Bootstrap class loader can load them, and given that class definition is unique per class loader (guaranteed by the [JVM spec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35901086/4483113))

> In other words, can I rely on this behavior in my application to serialize and deserialize Class objects

Yes

Comment: Sure `Class`es are cached by the classloader, what was surprising to me is the fact that deserializing a `Class` created in _another_ JVM instance preserves identity with `Class` instances in the current JVM instance. So if I use the standard deserialization logic of `ObjectInputStream`, use only a single classloader and don't have different definitions for classes with same canonical names, then I can be sure that identity of `Class` objects will be preserved after deserialization?

Comment: Notice that this you refer to as "Class" is in fact an instance of class `Class` (sorry for the tongue-twister). So you can't have multiple instances per classloader representing the same class FQN. Therefore the answer is yes, you can be sure

Comment: Also notice that deserializing a serialized object (from any class including `Class`) may lead to errors if the versions differ...

Comment: I have just created an answer that maybe is of your interest: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35901086/4483113

Comment: Hi just edited my response. `java.lang.Class` can not be loaded by a different class loader, so it is guaranteed

Comment: If I try to deserialize the object from a JVM where the class DeserializationTest is not loaded, would it be able to deserialize? In other words, is class level metadata stored in the serialized file?

Answer (score 0):

> How is Java able to deserialize objects in this case so that identity is preserved? `Class` doesn't seem to implement `writeObject()/readObject()/readResolve()`.

It doesn't need to implement `readObject()` or `writeObject()` to accomplish this, but it could do it by implementing `readResolve()`, or by special logic in `ObjectInputStream`.

Comment: Thanks, but this should be a comment, not an answer. I edited my post mentioning that `Class` doesn't have `readResolve()` either.

Comment: It is not a comment. I have now quoted the question that is answered by this answer. As it appears to have been an incorrect answer, I have amended it.